# How do I put commas in the right places generating JSON in MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm trying to not have a comma after a curly brace if it was the last item.

```
  for $row in /md:row
  let $test := $row/md:test/text()
  let $last := $row/*[fn:position() = fn:last()]

  return (
   '{
    "test": {
    "type": "test",
    "test": [',$testa,',',$testb,']
    }      
   }',
   if($last)
   then ''
   else (',')
  )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the given situation, where your output is JSON, use the `json:transform-to-json` call provided by MarkLogic for the purpose.

```
import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
  at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

json:transform-to-json(
  <json type="array" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">{
    for $row in /md:row
    let $test := $row/md:test/text()
    return (
      <json type="object">
        <test type="object">
          <type type="string">test</type>
          <test type="array">
            <item type="string">{$test}</item> <!-- testa and testb were undefined -->
            <item type="string">{$test}</item>
          </test>
        </test>
      </json>
    )
  }</json>
)
```

---

Among the issues this avoids:

- You don't need to add syntactical commas *at all* -- they're completely generated by the `transform-to-json` call, mooting that entire set of issues.
- Inadvertently malformed output (if your XML text node contains characters that need to be escaped to be valid in JSON -- this is true of newlines, for instance).
- Injection attacks (if your `$testa` or `$testb` contains `test", "hello", "world", "foo` then you'd have extra separate elements in your JSON code; more aggressive attacks could escape the structure and add completely new dictionaries to your outer list).

Comment: Thanks for informing about the issues.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of detecting the last element and handling this within your loop, use `string-join`, which automatically does what you want:

```
string-join(
  for $row in /md:row
  let $test := $row/md:test/text()
  let $last := $row/*[fn:position() = fn:last()]
  return (
   '{
    "test": {
    "type": "test",
    "test": [',$testa,',',$testb,']
  },
", ")
```

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd call this (generating JSON via string concatenation) *very* bad practice (easily prone to injection attacks, malformed output, etc). Just as we frown on folks generating XML by concatenating strings, generating JSON in such a way has similar pitfalls. See https://docs.marklogic.com/json:transform-to-json as an alternative.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't notice the MarkLogic tag! I'm very aware that this is not recommended, and I promise I don't do it at home :)

Comment: I updated the answer due to the bad practice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with Charles's comments, and I like wst's string-join better than this, but for the sake of completeness, there is also the `at` statement that is part of FLWOR expressions. You could use it something like this:

```
  let $rows := (1 to 10)
  let $last := fn:count($rows)
  for $row at $index in $rows
  let $test := string($row)

  return (
   '{
    "test": {
    "type": "test",
    "test": [',$test,']
    }      
   }',
   if($index eq $last)
   then ''
   else (',')
  )
```

HTH!